# Three clone women meet male triplets

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, clones

Another anthology short story I read early 1980s.

In the future cloning is available.  However clones are looked down upon and considered second-class citizens or worse.

The MCs are a trio of female clones who were created from a woman who was independent and forward-thinking, a scientist or businesswoman. She valued them but they find life difficult dealing with other more hostile people.

They travel together to, I think, a colony planet where they run into a nice man who, it turns out, is himself a triplet. The three brothers accept the clones as being just like themselves.

They all live happily ever after.